# В Yii2 обращаются к БД в контроллере?

Tags: yii2

Нашёл такой пример в нём к БД обращаются в контроллере. Так и надо или это ошибка?
В контроллере:

```
  public function actionShow()
    {
        $array = ArticlesList::getAll();
        return $this->render('articles',['dataInView' => $array]);
    }
```

В модели

```
class ArticlesList extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
      public static function tableName()
      {
             return 'articles'; // Имя таблицы в БД
      }

      public static function getAll()
      {
             $data = self::find()->all();
             return $data;
      }
}
```

И зачем тут статическая функция. Это нормально или неправильный пример?

Comment: Разработчики yii, утверждаю, что для них это нормально . У него философия такая - чем проще, тем лучше.

Comment: @XYZ а чем плохая философия? Весь сахар в том, что как желаешь так и делай, не всегда есть время на "продумать архитектуру" и тратить на это драгоценные минуты/часы, не всегда делаешь проект который "стрельнёт" и нужно будет долго поддерживать, так зачем нам сложно то?

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере контроллер обращается к БД не напрямую, а через модель. 
Именно экземпляр класса модели достаёт данные из соответствующей таблицы БД. Что это за таблица, прописано в статической функции `tableName`.

В принципе, это классический пример для Yii2.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я правда не понял `обращается к БД не напрямую, а через модель` где тут модель. Метод getAll() в модели что ли?

Comment: Модель, это класс `ArticlesList`.